# how do i pass arguments to docker file for amazonlinux 2, so that it shows ouput?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, environment-variables, amazon-linux

Pass arguments to docker file?

This is the image of docker file I which I have created any entry point.
what I need to do is I want to pass arguments by the " docker run  argument" command so it shows output.
Please if anyone knows the solution.

[this is the docker file]

[1]

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget

ENTRYPOINT  wget -O- -q var1
CMD ["-c"]
```

[the command I want to execute]

[2]

```
docker run 4589p/newubuntu https://ifconfig.me/ip
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do as this form :

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

In your case:

```
docker run image:tag wget -O- -q var1 https://ifconfig.me/ip
```

`image:tag` was built by `dockerfile` file above.

Comment: Is there anyway to execute it by just this “docker run image:tag http//ifconfig.me/ip”